# View() keeps opening new XQuartz windows

Tags: r, macos, dataframe, rstudio, xquartz

Whenever I use the View() function for a dataframe in RStudio (Version 1.2.5001, macOS), a new XQuartz (2.7.11) windows open up with that dataframe table.

How do I prevent XQuartz from opening new tabs? I would prefer these dataframes to just be shown inside RStudio.

The reason I downloaded XQuartz in the first place was to solve the Error code "Invald active developer path" I got.